# Current drawn by MQ9 Sensor

Tags: circuit-analysis, sensor, circuit-design

Here is the [datasheet of the MQ9 sensor](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/904644/HANWEIELETRONICS/MQ-9/1)

I would like to be sure about the current drawn by this sensor. The datasheet doesn't say anything about that, but tt says the power **Ps** heating comsumption is about 340mW and the heating time is 60 to 90s

Is the current drawn just for 60 to 90s (o I=Ps/Vcc=340mW/5v=68mA) or should that be calculated when RL is inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MQ-9](https://www.electronicoscaldas.com/datasheet/MQ-9_Hanwei.pdf) uses a heater (a filament lamp more than likely) to produce a broad band of infra red spectrum. The quantities of gas present of the right molecule will absorb some of that light at a certain wavelength and this allows the sensor to estimate the gas mix percentage. The data sheet shows this: -

[image]

> *I would like to be sure about the current drawn by this sensor, the
> datasheet doesn't tell anything about that*

The heater voltage is 5 volts and the heater resistance is 33 Ω hence, the current is 151.5 mA typically.

RL doesn't play a role in the dominant current consumption of the device.

> *It says the power Ps heating consumption is about 340mW*

I expect that is an average power based on something around a 50% duty cycle (see picture below) or maybe the heater resistance rises as it warms and thus the power stated (340 mW) implies a hot heater resistance of 73.5 Ω.

[image]

The picture above taken from [this much better data sheet](https://www.electronicoscaldas.com/datasheet/MQ-9_Hanwei.pdf).